# Set State of Parent Widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am not sure I have built my code properly, but I was trying to save time on my first app project.

I have a page where I will be generating several selection buttons that I want text added to a list when you push this button. I chose not to build a traditional button but instead it goes to another widget that I can control the state with.

The problem i am having, is this selector button seems to be working fine. It changes and to verify it is being added to the list, I have it printing to the console and can see it.

The problem is my display container is not updating when I select the button.

I have tried a global key, but the problem is that since the buttons are getting generated, they share a global key. 1 button seems to be fine, I can pass the key along, but I am also limited in my knowledge of all this, so I could be doing something wrong.

My current path to the code is the following.
Main Page -> Categories -> Sub Categories -> Page(digital in this case) -> Tags(the buttons).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:onlytagsprod/widgets/tag.dart';

final digital = new GlobalKey<DigitalState>();

class Digital extends StatefulWidget {

  Digital({ Key key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  DigitalState createState() => DigitalState();
}

class DigitalState extends State<Digital> {

  final postRefresh = ChangeNotifier();

  bool digitalSelected = false;
  List digitalHash = new List();
  String displays;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  callback() {
    setState(() {
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff0E0E0F),
        appBar: AppBar(
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(
            color: Color(0xffff9900),
          ),
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          title: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "#",
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 25,
                    color: Color(0xffff9900),
                    fontFamily: 'Dokyo'),
              ),
              Text(
                "digital",
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontFamily: 'Dokyo'),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
        body: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            flex: 3,
            child: Container(
                child: Row(
                  children: <Widget>[
//Display the List here*********************************************
                for (var digitalHashs in digitalHash)
                Text(
                digitalHashs,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20))
                  ],
                ),
                color: Colors.blue),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 6,
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.black,
              child: ListView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25, 5, 25, 5),
                children: <Widget>[
                  Tag(
                    tag: "#Digital",
                    isSelected: digitalSelected,
                    list: digitalHash,
                  ),
                  Tag(
                    tag: "#DigitalLife",
                    isSelected: digitalSelected,
                    list: digitalHash,
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )
        ]));
  }
}
```

This display page i want to be able to add as many Tag options as I want.

This is the Tag Page.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:onlytagsprod/subpages/digital.dart';

class Tag extends StatefulWidget {
  final String tag;
  bool isSelected;
  List list;
  Function(List) callback;

  Tag(
      {Key key,
        @required this.tag,
        @required this.isSelected,
        this.list,
      this.callback})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  _TagState createState() => _TagState();
}

class _TagState extends State<Tag> with SingleTickerProviderStateMixin {
  AnimationController _animationController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _animationController =
        AnimationController(vsync: this, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300));
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    super.dispose();
    _animationController.dispose();
  }

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 5, 0, 5),
      height: 50,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: widget.isSelected ? Color(0xffff9900) : Colors.black,
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
      child: InkWell(
        onTap: () {
          _handleOnPressed();
        },
        child: Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                child: Text(
                  widget.tag,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 20,
                      color: widget.isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                      fontFamily: 'Dokyo'),
                )),
            Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 0, 20, 0),
                child: AnimatedIcon(
                  icon: AnimatedIcons.home_menu,
                  progress: _animationController,
                  color: widget.isSelected ? Colors.black : Colors.white,
                ))
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _handleOnPressed() {
    setState(() {
      widget.isSelected = !widget.isSelected;
      widget.isSelected
          ? _animationController.forward()
          : _animationController.reverse();
      widget.isSelected ? widget.list.add(widget.tag) : widget.list.remove(widget.tag);
      print(widget.list);
    });
  }
}
```

The code has gotten a bit sloppy since I have tried every way I know how to address the state change... so I am aware of the unneeded stuff.

I am just at my newbie wits end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to get state changes to a parent or ancestor is via a callback method. That being said, you already define a `callback` field in the `Tag` class, but neither the build method in the parent widget nor the `_TagState` class is referencing it at all.

All you should need to do is change the `_handleOnPressed` method to execute the callback:

```dart
void _handleOnPressed() {
  ...
  widget.callback?.call(widget.list);
}
```

and change the constructors for `Tag` in the parent widget to assign them:

```
Tag(
  tag: "#DigitalLife",
  isSelected: digitalSelected,
  list: digitalHash,
  callback: (list) => setState(() => digitalHash = list),
),
```

Comment: Your amazing! There is a slight problem, and hopefully I can figure it out. But now the isSelected is not be handled properly, so its not removing from the list when I click it. But other that that, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: @Bnd10706 My guess is because the UI is now refreshing properly, you've exposed a bug elsewhere in your code that you wouldn't have known about before. If it becomes an issue, it may warrant a separate question.

Comment: yep my guess too. Thank you for solving the first problem though!

Comment: Ok, I think i found it, but it is based on your code. In your call back your setting the state of the list, but the isSelected from the Tag is not being saved. Is that something we can change in the call back?

Comment: @Bnd10706 The signature of your existing callback is just passing a `List`. If you want to save the `isSelected`, change the signature to `void Function(List, bool)` and pass that variable as well, i.e. `widget.callback?.call(widget.list, widget.isSelected);` and make the necessary changes in the parent widget as well to handle the additional data.

Comment: On a separate note, you should only have final fields in a widget class. Any non-final fields are considered stateful, and as such they should go in the state class. But in reality, `Tag` doesn't even need to be stateful. You can have it be a `StatelessWidget` and pass the changes to the callback, which will update the `Tags` when the parent widget calls `setState`. The rule of thumb in Flutter is to have as few `StatefulWidget`s as possible.

Comment: THe problem is I am going to have hundreds of tags, and I wanted to avoid have hundreds of bool variables.

Comment: @Bnd10706 You could always have a `Map<String, bool>` instead of separate booleans. Or a `Map<String, TagModel>` with an entire `TagModel` class that stores all the info necessary for each tag. Then build the list of tags using a builder approach rather than manually creating each one.

Comment: This sounds like the better approach... but being so new to programming and Flutter, I would not know where to begin.

Comment: @Bnd10706 This is getting into proper state management techniques which you will want to learn eventually, but for just starting out and making little projects I'm not sure I would worry about it just yet.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202598/discussion-between-bnd10706-and-abion47).

Comment: thank you again for all your advice, I asked you one more question in chat. Again, I appreciate it all! Given me lots of thought.